# View the sql queries used in to generate the report in Crystal Reports 2011

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I got this .rpt file that is not done by me. I need to view the sql queries used to generate the report in Crystal reports.

I tried clicking, Database -> Show SQL queries. It just prompted me to enter some variables and when I click OK. It prompted me to enter userid and password.

Do I need to be connected to the database in order to do so? I only need to extract the queries, I do not actually need to run it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using crystal report 2011, version 14 btw.

Comment: This might be useful http://community.dynamics.com/product/gp/gptechnical/b/gpvictoriayudin/archive/2009/02/19/how-to-get-a-definition-of-your-crystal-report.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be attached to database. Don't know why, but I don't know any workaround.

Solution suggested by Raihan (use File->Export) still need to set attachment to db.